# Why is are my BelongsToMany associations not working in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have users, teams and teams_users tables in my DB. When I create a new team, I want to save the team and users and some additional information to the join table. However, CakePHP 3 does not appear to recognising the relationship between users and teams.

\Model\Table\UsersTable.php

```
$this->belongsToMany('Teams', [
    'joinTable' => 'teams_users',
]);
```

\Model\Table\TeamsTable.php

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'joinTable' => 'teams_users',
]);
```

\Model\Table\TeamsUsersTable.php

```
$this->belongsTo('Teams');
$this->belongsTo('Users');
```

\Controller\TeamsController.php

```
function Create() {
...
    $user = $teamsTable->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
    $user->_joinData = $teamsTable->TeamsUsers->newEntity();

Error: Table "App\Model\Table\TeamsTable" is not associated with "TeamsUsers"
```

Comment: you have to use the [through](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option) option

Comment: Should it be though TeamUsers or TeamsUsers? - neither seems to work anyway.

Comment: it depens on how do you name your Table object and your database table. You can name it as you like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be using the [through](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option) option

then there are many thinks you can do:

then _joinData do not need to be  `TeamsTables` object, can be a simple Entity (see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations)):

```
$user->_joinData = new Entity();
```

Or you can load your model

```
$this->loadModel('TeamsUsers')
$user->_joinData = $this->TeamsUsers->newEntity()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end did it like this:

Thanks for all the good advice. Did it like this in the end:

```
if ($this-request->is('post')) {
            $team = $this->Teams->patchEntity($team, $this->request->data);
            $user = $this->Teams->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
            $teams->save($team);

            $user->_joinData = new Entity();
            $user->_joinData->nickname = $nickname;

            $this->Teams->Users->link($team, [$user]);
            $teams->save($team);
        }
```